# Inserting average value of list in map

Tags: java

I'm creating an application that scans for Bluetooth Beacons. I have a method that creates a map which contains the ID (MAC ADDRESS) of the beacon and the 10 recent RSSI values belonging to that beacon as a list. It looks like this:

```
public Map<String, List<Integer>> addToMap(Map<String, List<Integer>> mapToReturn, String beaconUID, Integer beaconRSSI) { 

List<Integer> temp = mapToReturn.get(beaconUID);

if (temp == null) {             
    temp = new ArrayList();
}

if (temp.size() >= 10) {             
    temp.remove(0); 
}

temp.add(beaconRSSI);

mapToReturn.put(beaconUID, temp); 

return mapToReturn; 
}
```

The bluetooth scanner runs every second and the map can look like this:

```
beacon1, [-55, -55, -54, -54, -55, -54, -54, -54, -54, -55]
beacon2, [-61, -61, -61, -61, -60, -61, -60, -61, -60, -60]
beacon3, [-69, -69, -68, -68, -68, -69, -70, -68, -69, -69]
```

I want to have a new map where the ID is the key again but the value is an average value of the list. I want to add a new average value to a list each time the scanner runs, but only have 2 items in the list (i remove the first index after each run). After two iterations it would look something like this:

```
beacon1, [-54,2, -55,6]
beacon2, [-61,2, -60,1]
beacon3, [-68,9, -70,0]
```

I made a method very similar to the first one for that.

```
public Map<String, List<Float>> addAverage(Map<String, List<Float>> mapToReturn, String beaconUID, Float beaconRSSI) {

    List<Float> temp = mapToReturn.get(beaconUID);

    if (temp == null) {
        temp = new ArrayList();
    }

    if (temp.size() >= 2) {
        temp.remove(0);
    }

    temp.add(beaconRSSI);
    mapToReturn.put(beaconUID, temp);


    return mapToReturn;
}
```

I've tried something like this. The map map contains the 10 recent values:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().size() >= 10) {
    addAverage(RSSIAverageMap, scanResult.getBleDevice().getMacAddress(),getAverageNumber(entry.getValue())));
}
}
```

This just returns the same value for all items in the RSSIAverageMap map. Am I doing something wrong? Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a class `Beacon` that does the work (collect the raw data, calculate the average, keep only the last 10 resp. 2 values):

```java
public class Beacon
{
    private java.util.LinkedList<Integer> rawValues=new java.util.LinkedList<>();
    private java.util.LinkedList<Double> averages=new java.util.LinkedList<>();

    public void addRaw(Integer value)
    {
        rawValues.add(value);
        calculateAverage();
        if(rawValues.size()>10)
            rawValues.removeFirst();
    }

    private void calculateAverage()
    {
        Double average=rawValues.stream().collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.averagingDouble(Integer::doubleValue));
        averages.add(average);
        if(averages.size()>2)
            averages.removeFirst();
    }

    public List<Double> getAverages()
    {
        return averages;
    }

    public List<Integer> getRawValues()
    {
        return rawValues;
    }
}
```

Then your work gets simpler because you only have to add the raw data:

```java
java.util.Map<String,Beacon> beacons=new java.util.HashMap<>(); 

public void add(String beaconId, Integer rawValue)
{
    //adds a new beacon for a new beaconId
    map.computeIfAbsent(beaconId,beaconId->new Beacon()).add(rawValue);
}
```